# How to populate and update record when I save another (Mongoose)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In this application I have 3 models PS, ENG and Patient
I need to populate and update Patient in specific field when create/update PS or ENG

**ENG Model**

```
'use strict';
const   mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ENGSchema = new Schema({
    eng_name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Kindly enter the name of the ENG']
    },
...
    eng_ur: String,//This is Patient number 
    eng_inout: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Inpatient', 'Outpatient'],
        ref: 'Patient'
    },
    eng_inout_date: { type: Date, ref: 'Patient' },
    eng_inout_loc: { type: String, ref: 'Patient' },
    eng_inout_reason: { type: String, ref: 'Patient' },
...

module.exports = mongoose.model('ENGs', ENGSchema);
```

**Patient Model**

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PatientSchema = new Schema({
...
    patient_status: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ENGs'||'PSs'},
    patient_inout_date: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ENGs'||'PSs'},
    patient_inout_loc: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ENGs'||'PSs'},
    patient_inout_reason: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ENGs'||'PSs'},
...
module.exports = mongoose.model('Patients', PatientSchema);
```

Now as I understand I need to create a middleware for PS and ENG model like `pre('save')` or I can do it in my controller.

**ENG Controller**

```
'use strict';

const   mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        ENG = mongoose.model('ENGs'),
        Patient = mongoose.model('Patients'),...;

exports.create_eng = (req, res)=> {
    let token = getToken(req.headers);
    if(token){
        req.body._user = checkPermissionReturnUserName(token);
        let new_eng = new ENG(req.body);
        new_eng.save((err, eng)=> {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            else{
                res.json(eng);
//Something wrong here?
                        Patient.findOne({patient_ur: this.eng_ur})
                            .populate({select: 'patient_inout_loc', path: new_eng.eng_inout_loc})
                            .exec(function (err, patient) {
                            console.log(patient.patient_inout_loc) //undefined

                        })
//tried this
Patient.findOne({patient_ur: new_eng.eng_ur})
                            .populate({path:'patient_inout_loc', select:'eng_inout_loc', model: ENG})
                            .exec( (err, patient)=> {
                                if (err) res.send(err);
                                else res.json(patient);
                            });
//

            }
        });
    } else return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Unauthorized.'});

};
```

What is wrong here?

Can I do like this(need to be able to populate from PS or ENG?

```
patient_inout_loc: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ENGs'||'PSs'}
```

Can not get it from the mongoose documentation. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you actually mean *"put an object in the referenced model as well as the parent"* here, as `.populate()` is a different thing entirely. That method is used to "retrieve" and not "create". The "pre save" seems to be actually what you are talking about here. So are you actually asking how to include your created `Patient` within the `ENG` object? Which way around does your actual request happen? A hook for example can look for the "new" `Patient` added to `ENG` and then "create" the `Patient`. But the other way around would be different.

Comment: I don't think  `ref: 'ENGs' || 'PSs'` does anything. `ref: 'ENGs' || 'PSs'` is the same as just saying `ref: 'ENGs'`